# Android Things crash folder overcrowded

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, iot, android-things

I develop an application on my Raspberry Pi 3,

Sometimes, I can't build my APK because the size of folder :

"data/misc/crash-reporter/crash" increase to 2.2GB.

whenever my application crash, this folder increase its size.

So, sometimes I'm obliged to empty the folder.

How to prevent data from accumulating in the "crash" fodler ?

```
rpi3:/ # cd data/misc/crash_reporter/crash
rpi3:/data/misc/crash_reporter/crash # ls
supplied_hci_thread.20171110.160745.406.core      supplied_hci_thread.20171110.160940.406.meta   supplied_hci_thread.20171110.162458.410.core  supplied_hci_thread.20171110.165237.410.fail.log
supplied_hci_thread.20171110.160940.406.fail.log  supplied_hci_thread.20171110.162202.2116.core  supplied_hci_thread.20171110.165025.410.core  supplied_hci_thread.20171110.165237.410.meta

rpi3:/data/misc/crash_reporter # du -sh *
2.2G    crash
4.0K    crash_sender
4.0K    guid
4.0K    lock
12K     log
4.0K    run
8.0K    spool
324K    tmp
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you filed a bug in the [Android issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192720%2B)?

Comment: I will do it, it's true that Android Thing is an OS not yet very stable